# Your advices about creating web application from database arbitrary structure

Tags: asp.net

I want to create web application. I use SqlServer 2008 and asp.net (framework 3.5 sp1).
In my task, user can create database arbitrary structure. and i must write system that generate web site by template. is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly possible... but not trivial.  You have to first create a database structure to hold the "metadata" about the user-generated table.  Then you can write a routine that converts the metadata to an actual table structure.  Your application can then have a standard search/add/edit/delete screen that reads the table structure and dynamically renders the columns on the page.

If you want your user to create a relational database (multi-table), then you are in for a great deal of pain... the metadata will get much more complex, and the editing screens will become much harder to manage.

Frankly, this is a good reason to check out Salesforce.com

RO

Comment: if I use, asp.net and sql server, i think the best way using 
mvc framework for search/add/edit/delete screens (generating controller, view) and for model entityframework. what you think about this? or you can prefer something else?

Comment: That's certainly one approach.  The ability to create databases from the EF is added in VS2010... you'll be on the bleeding edge.

Comment: how can i generate EF model by C# code?
for example, I chose db from browser, and then in server generate EF and save in server.

Comment: There's a pretty good discussion of how to do this in Visual Studio Magazine:

http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2008/09/01/customize-code-generation-in-ef.aspx